# Why debugger is not able to display/watch the struct into the deque?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

When I debug the small piece of code below, visual studio debugger doesn't show the value of the `struct` I pushed into the `deque`, it just show **all fields name = ???**. All the other var are correctly watched!

does someone already have the same issue ?

```
typedef struct ToTestDrift{
    int num;
    uint64_t pts;
    ToTestDrift(int n, uint64_t ts): num(n), pts(ts) {}
    ToTestDrift(const ToTestDrift& ro):num(ro.num), pts(ro.pts) {}
} drift_t;

ifstream input("test.txt"); 
std::deque<drift_t> drift; 
while(!input.eof())
{
    int framenum;  uint64_t pts;
    input >> pts >> framenum;  
    push_back(drift)(framenum, pts);
}
```

NOTE: I use a boost range adaptor to push_back, but it's the same with `drift.push_back` !

And if I extract a value like in the following code, in taht case a `watch`on `t` is OK...

```
  BOOST_FOREACH(frame_info_t t, tocheck)
  {
    if(t.pts != 0)
    { 
      fprintf(stdout, "%d \t %0.2f \t %0.e2f \t %d \t %d \n", t.framenum, t.pts, t.drift, t.period, t.type);
    }
  }//*/
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Just a personal recommendation: _Always_ initialize all variables.

Comment: Possibly unrelated, but you do know that `while (!input.eof())` will probably not work as you expect? The reason being that the `eofbit` flag is not set until *after* you try to read from beyond the file. Instead remember that the input operator `>>` returns the stream, and that streams can be used as conditionals, so you can do e.g. `while (input >> pts >> framenum)`.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio?  It works fine in 2012 and 2013 for me.  You're debugging a debug build and not a release build right?

Comment: @RetiredNinja Hi I'm still in the old age :) using visual studio 2008! And yes I'm in debug mode... my team and I use the same template project with the same debug setting for each vs project.

Comment: I just added some details & snapshot

Comment: Hmm, I don't remember having this issue with 2008, but I don't use `deque` often.  You might try a `vector` instead just to see if all containers are broken or not.  If `vector` works then you should take a look at the `autoexp.dat` file and see what's different between the two visualizers.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I did it and it leads to the same behavior !

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thank for your help, I finally found where was the issue. The code compiled and worked but it wasn't really C++ compliant! Thanks to GCC I understood yesterday that we cannot use struct defined in a function within any template container. See the answer I will post soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the reason behind that weird issue.

The code I provided is **not C++98 compliant and shouldn't compile** (in fact it doesn't compile with **GCC**). The reason is that we can't use a local to a function, struct/class definition, with a template (container or other...), [read that post for more info](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/457331-why-cant-local-structure-used-vector).

And in fact in the visual compiler accept that code, as there is no ID for the struct/class and for their fields, the debugger is "a bit lost"....

**I moved the struct/class definition out-side my function, and now the compiler create an ID for the struct/class and the debugger works as usual.**

So instead of

```
int function() 
{
    typedef struct ToTestDrift{
        int num;
        uint64_t pts;
        ToTestDrift(int n, uint64_t ts): num(n), pts(ts) {}
        ToTestDrift(const ToTestDrift& ro):num(ro.num), pts(ro.pts) {}
    } drift_t;

    ifstream input("test.txt"); 
    std::deque<drift_t> drift; 
    while(!input.eof())
    {
        int framenum;  uint64_t pts;
        input >> pts >> framenum;  
        push_back(drift)(framenum, pts);
    }
}
```

Write

```
typedef struct ToTestDrift{
            int num;
            uint64_t pts;
            ToTestDrift(int n, uint64_t ts): num(n), pts(ts) {}
            ToTestDrift(const ToTestDrift& ro):num(ro.num), pts(ro.pts) {}
        } drift_t;

    int function() 
    {
        ifstream input("test.txt"); 
        std::deque<drift_t> drift; 
        while(!input.eof())
        {
            int framenum;  uint64_t pts;
            input >> pts >> framenum;  
            push_back(drift)(framenum, pts);
        }
    }
```

**NOTE** that the first version of the code is compliant with the new C++11, all new compiler relaxed that limitation, so local function definition of a struct/class should work fine with visual studio 2013.

Comment: Ah, from the question it wasn't clear that it was a local structure.